# Crear servidor ioT con Node.js y MQTT

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket, socket.io, mqtt

Estoy intentando hacer un servidor para IoT en Node.js, comencé a trabajar con socket.io. Leyendo descubrí que una solución mas eficiente es utilizar el protocolo MQTT, la cuestión es que no se que librería utilizar o si hay forma de que socket.io utilice MQTT.

PD: la idea es, no utilizar agentes de mensajes ya creados, quiero manejar las comunicaciones desde mi propio servidor.

Comment: Qué haz intentado? Adjuta tú código

Comment: Lo único que tengo en el código es un server básico con express y socket.io, no hay nada implementado con MQTT